# Restoring Contract Records with Activated Status

Tags: contracts, backup, activate, restore

Looking at the market for Backup & Restore tools got me thinking about a limitation that we all face when working with Contract records, cannot insert records with a Status of Activated.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384828&language=en_US&type=1

Understanding these Backup & Restore tools use the metadata API and bulk API for restore operations, are they also faced with this database validation?

What is the expected “workaround” considering the backed up data should remain unchanged on restore in the event of disaster recovery?

Answer (score 1):

Start with ensuring the backup vendor uses a dedicated integration user

- Use a before save flow or trigger that detects the running user = Backup User and value of Contract.Status - if Activated, coerce it to Draft. Then the restore (insert) works

  - Also set a custom field `Was_Activated_Restored_as_Draft__c` to true
- Use an after save flow/trigger to see if running user is backup user and `Was_Activated_Restored_as_Draft__c` and then coerce back to Activated.